# Other than Baarle-Hertog/Baarle-Nassau, where in the EU can I take a selfie with my feet in two different countries?

Tags: borders, eu, photography, vantage-points

- In the EU
- Visible markers/lines

[image]

Comment: I expect the answer is "any marked Schengen land border" (and, depending on your definition of "country," the border between Northern Ireland and the Republic of Ireland). This photograph appears not to be a selfie.

Comment: This is too easy, there must be tens of marked _three_-country points, let alone just two.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Three-country points seem mostly to be in the middle of rivers, however, and therefore unmarked and more or less inaccessible,  with a few being more accessible by virtue of being on the tops of mountains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely almost all adjacent countries allow you to do this

- between Scotland and England  there are flags and signs you can stand next to on most routes
  [image]
- between Germany and France (pic from http://www.islandvulnerability.org/borders.html#df)
  [image]
- Between Spain and Gibraltar
- the list goes on and on, and pictures of many others can be found on that link above.

Comment: Between Spain and Gibraltar might not be possible. Are you sure that neither side's border officials ban photography?

Comment: No photography ban. I have taken various pictures all the way across the runway.